# Starting from Puerto Princesa, Philippines where is the nearest volcano that can be climbed in 2 or 3 days?

Tags: philippines, itineraries, trekking, volcanoes

Starting from Puerto Princesa in the Philippines where is the nearest volcano that can be climbed in 2 or 3 days?

Nearest means quickest to travel to, including via a commercial flight. (Excluding chartering a helicopter or anything like that).

The trek should be guided and take two or three days.  I don't have to reach the summit.

Should I go to Manila and then to Bulkang Mayon, or is there a closer option on a different island?

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for volcanoes, this map can be useful for you:

[image]
http://earthquakes.volcanodiscovery.com/

As you can see, the [Mayon volcano](http://www.volcanodiscovery.com/mayon.html) is really the nearest one to the Puerto Princesa.
[image]

But I think that more interesting variant is to go to the [Manado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manado), from it you can travel to 4 different volcanoes:

- [Karangetang](http://www.volcanodiscovery.com/indonesia/karangetang.html)
  [image]
- [Lokon-Empung](http://www.volcanodiscovery.com/lokon.html)
  [image]
- [Ibu](http://www.volcanodiscovery.com/indonesia/halmahera/ibu.html)
  [image]
- [Ducono](http://www.volcanodiscovery.com/dukono.html) (erupted in last month!)
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm going to share some of my research in an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are traveling to Puerto Princesa, it would wise to plan to go to Mayon Volcano before you go Puerta Princesa . Mayon Is Located on the same Island Manila is assuming your port of entry is Manila! Mayon is about a 10-15 hour car trip south. You could Fly into Legaspi City. the nearest domestic airport to Mayon. Mayo is showing activity and is currently spewing Lava as we speak!

If you want to check out Pinatubo, it is only a 2 hour drive North of Manila. Go stay in Angeles City, there are sight seeing helicopter trips, charter sightseeing  airplane flights or you can take an off road trip with a long hike at the end to the actual crater.